Postgres vacuum transaction idles for days
A few days ago we received the following error messages and started vacuum/analyze manually:
ERROR:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "xxxx"
HINT:  Stop the postmaster and vacuum that database in single-user mode.

We have auto vacuum configured the database had been running fine for years so I don't understand why we received the error.
Anyway, we started the vacuum/analyze on 11/23 and the database has been working fine but the vacuum transaction has been in idle state since 11/24.
 datid | datname | pid  | usesysid | usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |        backend_start         | xact_start |          query_start          |         state_change          | wait_event_type | wait_event | state | backend_xid | backend_xmin |                           query                           |  backend_type
-------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 16452 | XXXX | 7992 |       10 | postgres | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2024-11-23 05:09:41.97984-05 |            | 2024-11-24 11:36:01.526247-05 | 2024-11-24 11:36:01.768001-05 | Client          | ClientRead | idle  |             |              | vacuum (verbose,analyze) XXXX_XXXXXX.XXXXXX; | client backend
(1 row)

The database seems to be working OK and the cpu/memory utilization on the sever is within normal range.
Why the vacuum/analyze transaction is in idle state?
Postgres version: 10.16

That says state_change = 2024-11-24 11:36:01.768001-05 - what time was it when you checked that?

today 11/27 around 8:00

idle means that his query is done. The connection is still open, but waiting for the next query. But you have many problems, this could be the worst one, but you patch and maintenance processes could be part of this problem: Postgres version: 10.16. That's not the last patch of version 10 and version 10 is EOL for a few years now. Advice: Hire a DBA
